# Pokemon Go not displaying smaller roads

Tags: pokemon-go

I have had no trouble playing Pokemon Go on my iPhone 6. However, since this morning the map is not displaying smaller roads anymore.

I can't navigate in parks etc anymore, it's incredibly annoying. Already tried reinstalling the app. My boyfriend with the exact same phone has no trouble and still sees smaller roads.

How is it possible they 'disappeared' and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It's just as likely that the maps the game uses have been updated to use Google Maps's new info.  Will have an answer later, but I don't believe this is going to be fixable since it's a server side decision.

Comment: @NBN-Alex But how come all my friends still have the normal map and the google maps app on my phone still has all smaller roads as well?

Comment: The roads do still exist in real life though... Look up slightly ;)

Comment: @JamesWebster obviously, but if I am heading into a huge park I do not want to try and figure out which of the 6 paths I have to take.

Comment: I hope you're not wondering into parks at night but that being said, Phil bellow seems to be on the right track. Open up your google maps and check to see if you can see these smaller roads. Obviously not on satellite view. If not then re-install google maps or update it. This could be causing the problem. If it does show up try restarting your device as I suspect something may have gone wrong with the games sync to the devices maps app.

Comment: @Daniel as I said in other comments, my google maps is perfectly fine and there is no update available. Already restarted my phone, did not fix anything. Also I don't know what night has to do with anything. Or can you magically look through a bunch of trees and bushes at daytime?

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 that was more for a safety thing, not safe to be wondering around large parks at night. If none of these are the issue and you have tried re-installing the app itself, I can only think it would have something to do with the rendering of the game. But what puzzles me the most is that you saw them before, and your maps works fine... seeing as the game uses the maps app as its reference. Have you tried logging into your account from another device? Could be a device setting or something I'm missing. Another important question... is this the apk download?

Comment: @Daniel No, I'm using iPhone so APK is not even possible. It's the legit app store download, never participated in any illegal/risky things. I have not had the chance to log in on another device, but hope to have soon.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 I do not want to have to move this to a chat so will make this my last comment, try another device, if this is still a problem I have no solution for you I am truly sorry. I might have been able to debug the issue if it was android but I must confess my knowledge of IOS is not great. Best of luck, I know I was useless, but I tried.

Comment: Don't worry, you aren't the only one: https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4uti45/pokemon_go_smaller_roads_gone/

Answer (score 1):

I can't prove it but yesterday Google Maps published an updated version of their maps and as we know, Pokémon Go uses this data. There the streets don't have an outer darker border. Small roads seem to appear only barely visible. Maybe the engine in Pokémon Go can't handle this.

Comment: My google maps app is still displaying all roads though... And why would they only update this for certain users?

Comment: "My" App and the online Version also displays all streets. But as I said, they changed the "look and feel" of the images. If, for any reason, the Pokékon Go App uses an algorithm for these "old" Images and didn't mind the changes, it could be possible they can't detect the small roads.